# How to save a bool value into a memory location pointed to by a void*?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-punning

I have a `void* lhs_value` pointing to a sufficiently sized mallocated region of memory. I want to save a rvalue of type `bool` into it. Don't ask me why I wanted that. I think that this is as simple as casting that pointer to `bool*` and de referencing it. However the compiler complains. I am apparently doing something wrong. Can you help me with this?

```
 error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
                *((*bool) lhs_value) = true;
```

```
void* lhs_value;
lhs_value = malloc( sizeof(int) );
memset(lhs_value, 0, sizeof(int));
*((*bool) lhs_value) = true;
```

Comment: show us some code

Comment: @0x476f72616e I am showing that single line of code where I attempt to save `true` into the memory location pointed to by `lhs_value`. What else code do you want me to show?

Comment: Just hint: can you declare `*bool value;`?

Comment: @R2RT Upon certain circumstances, I may also be saving `short` and `int` values into this memory location.

Comment: Note the position of `*`. I phrased it badly: Is `*bool value;` valid C++ code?

Comment: You've placed one of the `*` in the wrong place.  `(*bool)` doesn't make sense where you have it. `(bool *)` will work.    Voting to close as this is essentially a typo.

Comment: @Peter How in the world did I not notice that?

Comment: Typos are like that.   Easy to do, the person who does them has trouble spotting them, easily spotted by someone else.    (Also, after time is passed, the person who made a typo can often see it easily too).    Similar thing happens in essays, books and journal articles all the time - someone writes something, when reading what they wrote they see what they intended to write rather than what they actually wrote.  Technically it's a form of cognitive bias that inflicts most humans.

Answer (score 4):

There's only one way to type pun correctly in C++:

```
#include <cstring>

bool value = true;
std::memcpy(lhs_value, &value, sizeof value);  // ::memcpy also ok
                                               // in which case #include <string.h>
```

Unions are not correct and pointer casts are not correct (although the pointer cast will work on a pointer returned directly from an allocation function, it is not required to work on all `void*` values to valid memory).

(Yes, you should have allocated memory in advance.  Use `malloc` only if you are passing the pointer to a C library which will call `free()` on it.  Otherwise use a proper C++ allocator like `::operator new()`.  `lhs_value = new bool(true)` is best of all, if you can cast back to the original type (`bool*`) when using the `delete` operator.
No, you should not intermix `sizeof (bool)` with `sizeof (int)` unless you test it is sufficient -- `sizeof (char) == 1` always but no guarantees on other built-in types.  No, you do not need to call `memset`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
   *static_cast<bool*>(lhs_value) = true;
```

be aware of [aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) before doing this; they are complex and hard to get right, and the symptom of getting them wrong is "the code works" until it breaks in a random way in a random spot after a compiler upgrade.

Comment: Is `static_cast` better/safer than `reinterpret_cast` in this case? I have no argument either way. It just _felt_ like a `reinterpret_cast` case to me so I have to ask.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `reinterpret_cast` is defined as "static_cast to `void*`, static_cast that result to the destination type".  Here is input is already `void*`.

Comment: @tedl so, reinterpret casts should be massive red flags in your code.  Static casting a void pointer, meanwhile, is less so; all void pointers are for is being cast out of.  It is no more a red flag than the `void*` was...

Comment: Thanks @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - I'll keep that in mind!